# I want to exit both foreach loop and while loop when opdnew<0

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

```
protected void btnOPDDetect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con1 = GetConnection();
    SqlConnection con = GetConnection();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    double opdnew;
    string batchNo = lblIdforReport.Text;

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ExpenseSheetNo,FurtherDetail,FurtherDetailBy,Id,VoucherStatus,Convert(nvarchar(50),Date,106) As Date,ProcessType,ProgramDepartment,CompanyPerson,PreparedBy,RecommendedStatus,Convert(nvarchar(50),PreparedDate,106) As PreparedDate,SubmittedBy,Convert(nvarchar(50),SubmittedDate,106) As SubmittedDate,RecommendedBy,Convert(nvarchar(50),RecommendedDate,106) As RecommendedDate,FurtherDetailBy,Supervisior,TotalAmount From tb_ManageExpenseSheetOne where IsCheckedAdvance='true' and FinanceOfficer='" + User.Identity.Name + "' and SubmittedStatus='Submitted' and   VoucherStatus='Voucher Created' and RecommendedStatus='Recommended' and  BatchNo='" + Convert.ToInt64(batchNo) + "'  order by ExpenseSheetNo", con);

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adapter.Fill(dt);

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        string PreparedBy = row["PreparedBy"].ToString();
        string TotalAmount = row["TotalAmount"].ToString();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HhrdApprovalSystem"].ConnectionString;

        string selectSql = "SELECT * from tb_Person where Name='" + PreparedBy + "'";

        SqlCommand cmdcheck = new SqlCommand(selectSql, con1);

        using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand())
        {
            try
            {
                con1.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmdcheck.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while(reader.Read())
                    {
                        TextBox13.Text = (reader["RemainingOPD"].ToString());
                        TextBox14.Text = TotalAmount.ToString();

                         opdnew = ((Convert.ToDouble(TextBox13.Text)) - (Convert.ToDouble(TextBox14.Text)));

                         if (opdnew < 0)
                         {
                             lblWarning.Text = "'" + PreparedBy + "' OPD is not enough";
                             break;
                         }
                     }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                con1.Close();
            }

            cmd1.CommandText = "Update tb_Person Set remainingOPD= '" + ((Convert.ToDouble(TextBox13.Text)) - (Convert.ToDouble(TextBox14.Text))) + "'WHERE Name ='" + PreparedBy.ToString() + "'";
            cmd1.Connection = con;

            con.Open();
            cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    btnArchive.Visible = true;
}
```

I have `RemainingOPD` column in `tb_Person` and `totalAmount` column in `tb_ManageExpenseSheetOne`. I have to subtract `totalAmount` from `RemainingOPD` and update `tb_Person`'s `remainopd` column.

For example,

tb_ManageExpenseSheetOne

| Name | totalAmount |
| --- | --- |
| A | 4000 |
| B | 5000 |
| C | 0 |

The `foreach` loop gets `PreparedBy` and `totalAmount` of all persons from `tb_ManageExpenseSheetOne`.

Then `while` loop to get `RemainingOPD` by subtracting `totalAmount` and also check if after subtracting `NewOPD` is less than 0.

If less than 0, then I want to show a message without updating any record in `tb_Person`.
Otherwise, I want to update `tb_Person` against all record from `tb_ManageexpensesheetOne`.

Comment: If you move that loop into a separate method, you can just return from the method... Or if you put the `btnArchive.Visible = true;` part into a `finally` block (with the rest of the code in a `try` block) you can return from the method right now.

Comment: Don't put your whole business logic into a button click handler. Use services and repositories to make it reusable. One class should only have one responsibility https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/may/csharp-best-practices-dangers-of-violating-solid-principles-in-csharp Your form class has only the responsiblity to show form elements. Call service methods to handle the events which itself uses respository methods to read or write to the database. After that you don't need to ask questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the whole `foreach` loop into a separate method and use the `return` to exit all the nested loops. For example:

```
    //new method
    private void CheckOPD()
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            ... your loop code

            while(reader.Read())
            {
                ...code
                if (opdnew < 0)
                {
                    return; // here you use a return
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And call this method inside the `btnOPDDetect_Click`.

Comment: I have checked this one .Here is the result. it updates all previous records before condition true. It updates all previous records. I want when opdnew < 0 then no record update.I want all records should update when condition is false for all records

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your code to achieve desired result:

```
protected void btnOPDDetect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    bool status = false;
    SqlConnection con1 = GetConnection();
    SqlConnection con = GetConnection();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    double opdnew;
    string batchNo = lblIdforReport.Text;

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ExpenseSheetNo,FurtherDetail,FurtherDetailBy,Id,VoucherStatus,Convert(nvarchar(50),Date,106) As Date,ProcessType,ProgramDepartment,CompanyPerson,PreparedBy,RecommendedStatus,Convert(nvarchar(50),PreparedDate,106) As PreparedDate,SubmittedBy,Convert(nvarchar(50),SubmittedDate,106) As SubmittedDate,RecommendedBy,Convert(nvarchar(50),RecommendedDate,106) As RecommendedDate,FurtherDetailBy,Supervisior,TotalAmount From tb_ManageExpenseSheetOne where IsCheckedAdvance='true' and FinanceOfficer='" + User.Identity.Name + "' and SubmittedStatus='Submitted' and   VoucherStatus='Voucher Created' and RecommendedStatus='Recommended' and  BatchNo='" + Convert.ToInt64(batchNo) + "'  order by ExpenseSheetNo", con);

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adapter.Fill(dt);

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        string PreparedBy = row["PreparedBy"].ToString();
        string TotalAmount = row["TotalAmount"].ToString();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HhrdApprovalSystem"].ConnectionString;

        string selectSql = "SELECT * from tb_Person where Name='" + PreparedBy + "'";

        SqlCommand cmdcheck = new SqlCommand(selectSql, con1);

        using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand())
        {
            try
            {
                con1.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmdcheck.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while(reader.Read())
                    {
                        TextBox13.Text = (reader["RemainingOPD"].ToString());
                        TextBox14.Text = TotalAmount.ToString();

                         opdnew = ((Convert.ToDouble(TextBox13.Text)) - (Convert.ToDouble(TextBox14.Text)));

                         if (opdnew < 0)
                         {
                             lblWarning.Text = "'" + PreparedBy + "' OPD is not enough";
                             status = true;
                             break;
                         }
                     }
                     
                     if(status)
                     {
                         break;
                     }
                     
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                con1.Close();
            }

            cmd1.CommandText = "Update tb_Person Set remainingOPD= '" + ((Convert.ToDouble(TextBox13.Text)) - (Convert.ToDouble(TextBox14.Text))) + "'WHERE Name ='" + PreparedBy.ToString() + "'";
            cmd1.Connection = con;

            con.Open();
            cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    btnArchive.Visible = true;
}
```